# Can't access method server on mobile side or via REST

Tags: wakanda

I have already asked this question, but the previous method I used was created in 4D. This time I created a new class in Wakanda and a new datastore class method. I know how to use it in mobile side, but it won't works, so I try to call it via REST and I have this following message :

"{"__ERROR":[{"message":"The \"method1\" attribute cannot be found in The \"TEST\" datastore class","componentSignature":"dbmg","errCode":1500},{"message":"The \"method1\" attribute cannot be found in The \"TEST\" datastore class","componentSignature":"dbmg","errCode":1500},{"message":"Error code: 1804\nCannot completely build a list of attributes with \"method1\" for the \"TEST\" datastore class\ncomponent: 'dbmg'\ntask 7963, name: 'HTTP connection handler'\n","componentSignature":"dbmg","errCode":1804}]}"

My method is in public scope, and I can access to the datastore class TEST via REST.

Can someone tell me how I can use this method, or what to do to correct this error ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error indicates the method1 is not publicly available under table TEST.

I tested and get the same exact error when the method scope is not set to public.

Please double check the code to change scope is correct, like following:

```
model.DataClass1.methods.method1.scope = 'public'
```

And see if method1 is indeed published in table TEST by accessing http://127.0.0.1:8081/rest/$catalog/TEST/

The response JSON should have method1 in its **methods** property:
[image]